# How to access variables passed to child queries

Tags: graphql

I want to be able to add parameters to subqueries, but I can't figure out how to get it to work.

I'm trying to write a schema with a viewer object which contains the queries I have so that I can return edges/nodes. I think I'm missing something fundamental about resolvers but, after a lot of googling, I still don't get it.

My schema looks like this (just the relevant bits):

```
type Query {
    viewer: Viewer!
}

type Viewer {
  allLinks(skip: Int, first: Int, last: Int, orderBy: 
    LinkOrderByInput): LinkConnection
}
```

LinkConnection is how you would expect, it has an edges attribute which is a list of nodes etc.

I'm using Prisma, and the resolvers look like this:

```
const allLinks = async (parent, args, context, info) => {
  const links = await context.prisma.linksConnection({
    first: args.first,
    orderBy: args.orderBy,
  })
  const count = await context.prisma
    .linksConnection()
    .aggregate()
    .count()
  return {
    pageInfo: links.pageInfo,
    edges: links.edges,
    count,
  }
}

export const viewer = async (parent, args, context, info) => {
  const links = await allLinks(parent, args, context, info)
  return { allLinks: links }
}
```

And then if I do this query:

```
query {
  viewer {
    allLinks(first: 1, orderBy:createdAt_DESC) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
        }
      }
      count
    }
  }
}
```

Then it runs without actually errorring, but it returns all of the links rather than just one, and I've played around with console.logging and it seems like the first and orderBy parameters aren't actually doing anything.

Can anyone help explain how I can structure my resolvers so that the arguments actually do something? It seems like this should be obvious!